# Storing user data upon login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to C# and ASP.NET, so please bear with me.

I'm making a site that consumes 2 different Web Services, that will hopefully use the user's individual accounts/api keys for each system. I take this information when the user creates an account on my system. I would like to retrieve this information from the database as soon as the user logs in, and store it in the Session so that I can use it every time my site calls one of the APIs.

I have tried:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
  {
     SiteEntities SiteDB = new SiteEntities();
     Session["user"] = SiteDB.T_USER.Find(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
     return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
  }

  // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
  //ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
  ViewBag.WarningMessage = "The user name or password provided is incorrect.";
  return View(model);
}
```

but, apparently this won't work because WebSecurity.CurrentUserId has not been set yet at this point.

My question is that if I wanted to grab the user's data as early as possible, so that it is available for the user's entire visit, where should I go about retrieving it?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the username in finding the details instead of the UserId so your code should look like the following

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
  {
     SiteEntities SiteDB = new SiteEntities();
     // ------- updated the below line to use username -------------------------------
     Session["user"] = SiteDB.T_USER.Find(model.UserName);
     return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
  }

  // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
  //ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
  ViewBag.WarningMessage = "The user name or password provided is incorrect.";
  return View(model);
}
```